# How to join by the most recent preceding date?

Tags: teradata

Imagine I have a database with historic price data and a second table with dates

[image]

A new row was entered into the price history table every time the price changed.

How can I (efficiently) join the two tables so that I can get the price each customer had to pay on that day?

I need the syntax for teradata, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid that I cannot guarantee 100% Teradata compatibility for my answer as there are, to my knowledge, no Teradata fiddles available. However, I have used PostgreSQL, one of the more standards compliant systems and there are no PostgreSQL specific constructs used in my answer (see the fiddle [`here`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=7a4df8b5723ba41ed6f6d97118086bec)), so I think we're good to go!

I glanced at the Teradata documentation for Window functions ([`LAG and LEAD`](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/756LNiPSFdY~4JcCCcR5Cw/GjCT6l7trjkIEjt~7Dhx4w)) and for Common Table Expressions ([`CTE`](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/0I5vemahub4iSU2bk5WA1A/jbHy7VP8_alFn7HeiWdHrw)s) and comparing it with PostgreSQL's syntax ([`Window`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-lag-function/) functions, [`CTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-with.html)s), it all seems fairly vanilla.

First thing I did was `CREATE` and populate the tables. As an aside, you should avoid using images on StackExchange for the reasons outlined in this [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/470530). Use text for DDL and DML or, better yet, provide a fiddle - if you can't find a Teradata one (I looked and couldn't), use something like PostgreSQL which should get you most of the way there.

Another small note, it's not a good idea to name your fields using [`SQL keywords`](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/coding-standards/list-of-sql-reserved-words). Liberal use of the `_` (underscore) character is a big help here.

```
CREATE TABLE price
(
  item_id TEXT NOT NULL,
  item_price SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  change_date DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO price 
VALUES 
('A', 249, '2014-09-01'),
('B', 129, '2014-09-01'),
('A', 299, '2014-08-25'),
('B', 139, '2014-09-25');
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE purchase
(
  customer_id SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  item_id TEXT NOT NULL,
  purchase_date DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO purchase
VALUES
(1, 'A', '2014-08-27'), (2, 'A', '2014-09-02');
```

I then ran the following queries - I've left in extraneous fields which aren't required for the final calculation so that my thought processes could be followed - using `LAG` and `LEAD` can be tricky and it's easy to mix up which field you should be comparing with which other one, so my policy is to leave them all in and let the OP (Original Poster - i.e. you) decide which you find useful and want to keep and which you wish to eliminate.

```
WITH pr_cte AS
(
  SELECT 
    p.item_id, 
    LAG(p.item_price, 1) 
      OVER (PARTITION BY p.item_id ORDER BY p.change_date) AS lag_price,
    p.item_price,
    LEAD(p.item_price, 1) 
      OVER (PARTITION BY p.item_id ORDER BY p.change_date) AS lead_price,
    LAG(change_date, 1, '2000-01-01') 
      OVER (PARTITION BY p.item_id ORDER BY p.change_date) AS lag_date,
    p.change_date,
    LEAD(p.change_date, 1, '2038-01-01') 
      OVER (PARTITION BY p.item_id ORDER BY p.change_date) AS lead_date
  FROM price p
  -- ORDER BY p.item_id, p.change_date -- not allowed in Teradata according to @dnoeth
)
SELECT * FROM pr_cte;
```

If you don't have a version with `CTE`s, you can always use a subquery.

Result:

```
item_id     lag_price   item_price  lead_price       lag_date  change_date  lead_date
      A                        299          249    2000-01-01   2014-08-25  2014-09-01
      A           299          249                 2014-08-25   2014-09-01  2038-01-01
      B                        129          139    2000-01-01   2014-09-01  2014-09-25
      B           129          139                 2014-09-01   2014-09-25  2038-01-01
```

Notice the use of the defaults `2000-01-01` and `2038-01-01` - I'm implicitly assuming that the prices before the specified dates in the `price` table go back to 2000 and that prices after will continue till 2038 when [`*nix time`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) will explode! Obviously, you can change these for values more suited to your use case. I've left it up to you to provide default prices, again as per your use case.

Then, I ran:

```
WITH pr_cte AS
(
  SELECT 
    p.item_id, 
    LAG(p.item_price, 1) 
      OVER (PARTITION BY p.item_id ORDER BY p.change_date) AS lag_price,
    p.item_price,
    LEAD(p.item_price, 1) 
      OVER (PARTITION BY p.item_id ORDER BY p.change_date) AS lead_price,
    LAG(change_date, 1, '2000-01-01') 
      OVER (PARTITION BY p.item_id ORDER BY p.change_date) AS lag_date,
    p.change_date,
    LEAD(p.change_date, 1, '2038-01-01') 
      OVER (PARTITION BY p.item_id ORDER BY p.change_date) AS lead_date
  FROM price p
  -- ORDER BY p.item_id, p.change_date -- see above and comment by @dnoeth
)
SELECT 
  pr.item_id, pr.item_price,
  pur.customer_id, pur.item_id, pur.purchase_date
FROM pr_cte pr
JOIN purchase pur 
  ON pr.item_id = pur.item_id
  AND pur.purchase_date >= pr.change_date
  AND pur.purchase_date < pr.lead_date;
```

Result (again, cull fields as you see fit):

```
item_id     item_price  customer_id     item_id     purchase_date
      A            299            1           A        2014-08-27
      A            249            2           A        2014-09-02
```

Which is, AFAICT, the correct answer. You may want to test with edge cases which I may have overlooked - if there's a problem, get back to me. +1 for an interesting and challenging question and welcome to the forum!

Comment: To execute it on Teradata you just need to remove the ORDER BY from the cte

Comment: @dnoeth - kinda makes sense - sometimes (can't remember when they are and when they aren't) `ORDER BY`s are excluded in subqueries also. I'll comment it out and refer the reader to your comment. Thanks!

Comment: In Standard SQL it used to be allowed in the outermost Select only. Now it's probably valid in any place when you use FETCH/LIMIT/TOP.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the actual data/indexes this approach might be more efficient:

```
WITH cte AS 
 ( -- combine both tables into one
   SELECT DISTINCT
      item_id
     ,purchase_date
     -- to be filled in the next step
     ,Cast(NULL AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS item_price
   FROM purchase
   UNION ALL
   SELECT
      item_id
     ,change_date
     ,item_price
   FROM price
 )
SELECT
   item_id
  ,purchase_date
  -- fill the NULLs in the purchase rows with the latest price
  ,Last_Value(item_price IGNORE NULLS)
   Over (PARTITION BY item_id
         ORDER BY purchase_date, item_price NULLS LAST) AS item_price
FROM cte
-- only return rows from the purchase table
QUALIFY cte.item_price IS NULL
```

Of course this returns the prices only, to get the customer info you need to wrap it into another CTE/Derived Table and join back to the purchase table.

Comment: How does `QUALIFY` differ from `HAVING`? I looked at the documentation and can't really get my head around the distinction! What is your result set for this query? The same as mine - no Teradata fiddle to test on - plus `QUALIFY` doesn't work on PostgreSQL.

Comment: QUALIFY is non-Standard syntax. You're right, it's adding a filter *after* calculating Window Functions, similar to HAVING after aggregation. The workaround is nesting it in a CTE/Derived Table and then `where item_price is null`.